# Does a React Native app need read/write permission on Android if using asyncstorage?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native app that uses expo.io. In the future I want to include options so save settings in the app which will use asyncstorage. Because of this I left permissions on the Android app saying “read the contents of your usb storage and modify or delete the contents of your usb storage”. If I remove those permissions will asyncstorage storage still work? If so where will asyncstorage storage save?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, asyncstorage works without any permission. It is like localstorage for the phones. As state in the docs,

For ios =>

> On iOS, AsyncStorage is backed by native code that stores small values in a serialized dictionary and larger values in separate files

and for android =>

> On Android, AsyncStorage will use either RocksDB or SQLite based on what is available.

For reference you can check https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html.
If you have any further queries please let me know so that i can help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes your asyncstorage storage will work. For Android it mostly uses SQLite and for IOS it stores large value in separate files. If you have used ReactJS, AsyncStorage is same as localStorage

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where it stores then?

Comment: For Android it mostly uses SQLite and for IOS it stores large value in separate files. If you have used ReactJS AsyncStorage is same as localStorage

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The answer is correct. I up voted to help offset.